# OutOfMemory при вызове cursor.getString()

Tags: android

Есть метод, которым я хочу прочесть бд и сформировать ArrayList объектов с одним лишь строчным полем, затем я хочу передать его в RecyclerAdapter, но получаю OOM. Где я ошибаюсь?

```
   recyclerAdapter2 = new RecyclerAdapter(getMenuCreatingArray(),this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter2);

}

public  ArrayList<MenuItem> getMenuCreatingArray (){
    ArrayList<MenuItem> newArrayCreating = new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("my_table", new String[]{"col_category"},null,null,null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
            menuItem.setCategory_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_CATEGORY)));
            newArrayCreating.add(menuItem);
        }
        cursor.close();
    return newArrayCreating;
}
```

Лог

```
02-08 17:45:34.370 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art: Throwing 
OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 64 byte allocation with 4 free bytes     and 4B until OOM" (recursive case)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x73ca4970 self=0xf4306800
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:   | sysTid=5612 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xf775c160
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 8773184420 55335465 599 ) utm=794 stm=82 core=2 HZ=100
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:   | stack=0xff05c000-0xff05e000 stackSize=8MB
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at com.example.vadik.alfatest.activitys.MainActivity.getMenuCreatingArray(MainActivity.java:87)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at com.example.vadik.alfatest.activitys.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-08 17:45:34.371 5612-5612/com.example.vadik.alfatest E/art:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: OOM всегда на одном и том же месте генерируется? А если перезагрузить устройство? `MenuItem` – это класс, разработанный Вами?

Comment: да, всегда  одном месте. MenuItem - неудачное  название класса созданного мной, который описывает данные для recyclerView. Перезагрузка  результатов не  дает

Comment: Какое значение возвращает метод `cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_CATEGORY)`?

Comment: Возвращает строку

Comment: Этот метод должен возвращать число, вопрос в том, какое. Запишите отдельно: `int i = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_CATEGORY)` и скажите, чему равно `i`,

Comment: @ post_zeew, Выдает NullPointerException. p.s. прошу прощения, что пропал

Comment: по-моему, после получения строки данных из курсора, его надо двигать вперед (`moveToNext()`), а так у вас бесконечный цикл заполняет список одним и тем же, пока память не кончится.

Comment: @ zRrr Да, точно!